# Printing datetime value from SQL in Python returns invalid result

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to get the `datetime` values from an SQL DB table like so:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP (10) [TimeLog] FROM [database].[dbo].[table]')
Car_Time = cursor.fetchall()
```

I then want to use this value inside an api, but when I print the value my it returns:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 3, 15, 25, 26, 170000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 13, 16, 5, 30000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 13, 34, 29, 77000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 14, 21, 6, 327000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 15, 59, 1, 983000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 16, 38, 41, 983000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 16, 40, 4, 47000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 9, 16, 47, 47, 77000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 10, 18, 14, 29, 890000), ), (datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 10, 18, 43, 16, 437000), )]
```

Why would this be? and how can I change it so that it is more representative of what is stored within the SQL table? As seen below:

```
2011-05-03 15:25:26.170 

2011-05-09 13:16:05.030 

2011-05-09 13:34:29.077 

2011-05-09 14:21:06.327 

2011-05-09 15:59:01.983

2011-05-09 16:38:41.983 

2011-05-09 16:40:04.047 

2011-05-09 16:47:47.077 

2011-05-10 18:14:29.890 

2011-05-10 18:43:16.437
```

Comment: you need add a for row in Car_Time

Comment: You’re getting a list of `datetime` objects, that’s all. There are many different ways to print them/format them as strings, I would suggest taking a look at the docs.

Comment: Study lists in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the representation of the datetime object in Python. You need to use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format your dates.

```
for ct in car_time:
    ct[O] = ct[O].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Antoher solution would be to do the formatting directly on the SQL Server side in order to return strings.

Something like this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP (10) CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), [TimeLog], 120) AS TimeLog FROM [database].[dbo].[table]')
```